# "CHECK", "CHECK OUT", "VIEW", "LOOK AT" SOMEONE'S PROFILE (Meaning and Difference)

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, difference

*In the context of a website*, for example, *a dating site*, I would like to know the meaning of the following expressions:

- "to check someone's profile"
- "to check out someone's profile"
- "to view someone's profile"
- "to look at someone's profile".

Do those expressions have to do with *turning one's eyes towards something* or do they mean *to examine something* or do they mean *to read something*?

What should I think of or should I imagine when I hear or see those expressions?

I have some examples:

> 1. *Someone likes your profile. Why not CHECK OUT their profile and see if you're interested*.
> 2. *Susan just VIEWED your profile!*
> 3. *Megan Fox just LOOKED AT your profile!*
> 4. *Alizee just CHECKED your profile!*

Comment: _View_ and _look at_ just mean, as you put it _turn your eyes towards_ it. _Check_ and _check out_ have more a sense of _examine to see if it's suitable._

Comment: @Kate Bunting So if you _check_ or _check out_ **a profile**, you want to examine it. But if you want to _view_ or _look at it_, you just want to take a look at it, something brief. Is that correct?

Comment: I don't suppose there is any great difference when it comes to looking at profiles on a website, but those are the literal meanings of the words.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of each example is the same. It is the connotation that is different. Connotation varies among subcultures, but for me Ex.1 brings a sense of excitement and a little urgency, implies new possibilities, and warrants a high level response (action or reply). Ex.2 is only informative, FYI, no sense of importance, and doesn't warrant a response. Ex.3 is also informative, but draws a level of curiosity that warrants a low level response. Ex.4 is informative as well but implies importance, perhaps as if one is waiting for such an notification.